# Javascript function scope - to use console.log or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, cleartimeout

Two functions:

**First:** Closes a stickyFooter that is fixed to the bottom of the page onclick of the cross.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 function closeSticky() {
    jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();
      jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed', 'yup', {
        path: '/',
        expires: 30
      });
    }
});
```

**Second:** This function fades in/fades out two divs, and stops when there's focus to an input area. What needs to happen now is when the stickyfooter is closed it needs to call the clearTimeout in this separate function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // check if both divs are visible
    if ((jQuery('.footerPromoBannerWrapper').is(':visible')) && (jQuery('.stickyFooter').is(':visible'))) {

        // Local variable for cancel of fades
        var stickyTimeout;

        // Set sticky as display:none
        jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();

        // Switch in
        window.switchIn = function () {
            jQuery('.footerPromoBannerWrapper').fadeToggle(function () {
                jQuery('.stickyFooter').fadeToggle(function () {
                    stickyTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                        window.switchOut();
                    }, 3000);
                });
            });
        };

        // Switch out
        window.switchOut = function () {
            jQuery('.stickyFooter').fadeToggle(function () {
                jQuery('.footerPromoBannerWrapper').fadeToggle(function () {
                    stickyTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                        window.switchIn();
                    }, 3000);
                });
            });
        };

        stickyTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            window.switchIn();
        }, 5000);

        jQuery('input#emailsignup').focus(function() {
            clearTimeout(stickyTimeout);

        });

    } // End of both divs are visible if statement
});
```

**Question:**

How do I combine both in order to call the timeOut feature as part of the close of the sticky footer? Something like this?

**First function amendment:**

```
function closeSticky() {
jQuery('.stickyFooter').hide();
jQuery.cookie('stickyNewsClosed', 'yup', {
path: '/',
expires: 30
});
stopAnimation();
}
```

**Second function amendment:**

```
function stopAnimation() {
jQuery('input#emailsignup').focus(function() {
clearTimeout(stickyTimeout);
});
} // End stopAnimation function
console.log(function stopAnimation());
```

Comment: are those 2 functions declared outside of the jquery dom ready scope?

Comment: What is `console.log(function stopAnimation());` supposed to do?

Comment: They are @eg_dac .Separately though.

Comment: i think your stickyTimeout variable is out of scope

Comment: Exactly, @eg_dac - how do I go about getting that pushed into the first function with use with the closeSticky?

Answer (score 1):

You have jQuery inside the functions, so i would suggest moving the 2 functions inside the dom ready scope. Your cleartimeout is probably calling in udefined.

Comment: Something like this perhaps then? (not working but valid):
http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/ptfY7/

Comment: one second, i will whip up something.

Comment: on that demo page, there is a js error, this could be causing the rest of the logic to fail

Comment: Everything is valid. I don't see it @eg_dac. Perhaps a problem with the reliance on the jquery.cookie plugin?